# send and receive a BigInteger value between two pc

Tags: java

I am working on an encrypted voip application with elliptic curves whose values ​​are of biginteger type and I must send the public key to the other host but I have a problem in sending this type exactly.

2.I tried some methods but still I have errors,this is a part of my code.

```
    OutputStream o = client.getOutputStream();
    InputStream inp = client.getInputStream();
    EllipticCurveAlgorithm algorithm = new EllipticCurveAlgorithm();
    PointProccessor processor = new PointProccessor();
    BigInteger pri = new BigInteger("1234567898514546");
    Point pub = processor.multiply(pri, algorithm.base);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(o);
    os.writeObject(pub.getX());
    os.writeObject(pub.getY());
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inp);
    BigInteger px = (BigInteger)ois.readObject();
    BigInteger py = (BigInteger)ois.readObject();
```

3.the error of this code is this.

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: FF7FFF7F
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)
at chat.VOIPClientEC.run(VOIPClient.java:681)
```

4.I hope that anywone can help me and suggest me an other solution.

Comment: Hi Meriem, have you checked this question, seems quite alike
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171635/java-invalid-stream-header-7371007e

Comment: I think that it is not the same because I send the data in an objectOutputStream and I recieve it from an ObjectInputStream so I use the same Object stream

Comment: Can you post line 681 of file `VOIPClient.java` ?

Comment: ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inp);
this is the line witch correspond to line 681